# How to skip some results using double for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem, so I made it simplified code, everything how it is here need to stay that way because of my bigger problem. I have 2 dictionaries and I have 2 for loops. I need to skip outputs with same result like AA, BB, CC etc... and I need to remove one of AB or BA, I need to keep AB, but I don't need BA. Can you help me with this problem, but I need to keep it simple for my real problem?

```
one = {
    "A" : "A",
    "B" : "B",
    "C" : "C",
    "D" : "D",
    "E" : "E",
    "F" : "F",
    "G" : "G",
    "H" : "H"
}
two = {
    "A" : "A",
    "B" : "B",
    "C" : "C",
    "D" : "D",
    "E" : "E",
    "F" : "F",
    "G" : "G",
    "H" : "H"
}

for botname,bot in one.items():
    for topname, top in two.items():
            print (str(bot) + str(top))
```

Output:

```
AA*
AB
AC
AD
AE
AF
AG
AH
BA*
BB*
BC
BD
BE
BF
BG
BH
CA*
CB*
CC*
CD
CE
CF
CG
CH
DA*
DB*
DC*
DD*
DE
DF
DG
DH
EA*
EB*
EC*
ED*
EE*
EF
EG
EH
FA*
FB*
FC*
FD*
FE*
FF*
FG
FH
GA*
GB*
GC*
GD*
GE*
GF*
GG*
GH
HA*
HB*
HC*
HD*
HE*
HF*
HG*
HH*
```

'*' it's not output, outputs with * I want to skip

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW, you can achieve this with `itertools.combinations("ABCDEFGH", 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just keep the pairs where `bot < top`. This will discard the duplicates where `top < bot`, as well as the pairs where `top == bot`.

```
for bot in one.values():
    for top in two.values():
        if bot < top:
            print(bot + top)
```

There's no need to use `.items()` if you're only using the values, not the keys.

Comment: Something to note is that this will work only if the values are strings in the same case. `"a" > "b"` evaluates to `False`, though `"a" > "B"` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Yeah, but if the overall goal is to just suppress duplicates without respect to order, then it doesn't really matter. So it might keep `aB` and skip `Ba`.

Comment: It does without order as you said, but for this I don't need by order. It is simple and work perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this, as it seems to have your desired output:

```
one = ["A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
two = one
s =""
for j in range(len(one)):
    for k in range(len(two)):
        if j != k:
            print(s.join([one[j],two[k]]))
```

At present the "two = one" part is kind of redundant because "two" is exactly the same as "one" here anyway so we could have just used "one" twice, but coding it this way gives the option for "one" and "two" to be different without breaking the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new set to store the opposite values that you've added to your list. For example:

- If you added AA or AB to your list, you can add AA and BA to your set.
- If you added BC or CD to your list, now your set comprises CB and DC
- Since sets only keep one distinct value, you can store the recurrent values without any extra write operations on memory.

So, after all, your code should look like this.:

```py
one = {
    "A" : "A",
    "B" : "B",
    "C" : "C",
    "D" : "D",
    "E" : "E",
    "F" : "F",
    "G" : "G",
    "H" : "H"
}
two = {
    "A" : "A",
    "B" : "B",
    "C" : "C",
    "D" : "D",
    "E" : "E",
    "F" : "F",
    "G" : "G",
    "H" : "H"
}

values = set()
for botname,bot in one.items():
    for topname, top in two.items():
      if bot != top and bot+top not in values: # checks if the value is not AA or already in values set (which consists of opposites of what we've printed already)
        print (str(bot) + str(top))
        values.add(top+bot)                    # add the opposite of the printed text to our set
```

Answer (score 1):

Combing with Barmar answer to 2 lines of code:

```
letterlist = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
output = [val+valb for val in letterlist for valb in letterlist if val<valb]
```

Your letterlist can also be the keys of the dictionaries:

```
dd = [val+valb for val in one.keys() for valb in two.keys() if val<valb ]
```